# N=2 SSM without a Higgs

Tags: standard-model, supersymmetry, research-level, higgs

In [arXiv:1012.5099](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5099), section III, the authors describe a supersymmetric extension to the standard model in which there is no Higgs sector at all, in the conventional sense. The up-type Higgs is a slepton in a mirror generation, and other masses come from "wrong Higgs" couplings to this particle. I'm wondering if this approach can revive the fortunes of N=2 supersymmetric extensions of the standard model, where there are three mirror generations, but which run into trouble with oblique electroweak corrections.

I realize that this may be, not just a research-level question, but a question which will require original research to answer! However, if anyone has an immediately decisive argument about the viability of such a theory, now's your chance. :-)

Comment: I am not a phenomenologist and ever heard of the N=2 extension of the SM. But, my knee jerk reaction is that since N>1 SUSY cannot be spontaneously broken it must be difficult to use for phenomenology. I may well be missing something.

Comment: I am also not sure what you mean by "mirror" generations. If these are fermions of opposite chirality, such that the complete theory is non-chiral, one would expect that generically all fermions would be massive. Chirality is what allows massless fermions in the standard model.

Answer (score 7):

You can get a realistic N=2 model in four dimensions from a N=1 higgsless model in 5 dimensions and use boundary conditions and warping to break both SUSYs: http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1379 (apologies for the self citation;).